# What is a stock in "stock block" and "stock fire"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to Merriam-Webster, a [stock block](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stock%20block) is a truncated obconical block of wood used as a pattern in making the hole for a stock fire in a forge. I was not able to find an image of a truncated obconical block of wood online - I wonder what pattern it has. I did a search on "stock fire", but only images of fire came up. Could someone explain to me what is a "stock" in this context? Thank you.

Comment: *Stock* is your input metal. Iron ingots for example. A *stock fire* is distinguished from an *open fire* in that unlike the latter, the former surrounds the stock with heat, by forming a special hole in the fuel, and sticking the stock in that hole. That way the stock can be heated all around, and the heat applied for many hours. The stock block is the special tool, a kind of form or mold, that creates the right shape (hole) in the fuel for your particular stock or use case. http://www.faadooengineers.com/online-study/post/me/basic-manufacturing-processes/1375/open-fire-and-stock-fire-furnace

Comment: Obconical just means an upside-down cone. If it's truncated, the point is cut off.

Comment: ... So you're left with a frustum. I bet some smiths made do with an inverted bowl.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about obscure domain-specific concepts, artifacts, and terminology that would be completely unknown to the average Anglophone.

Comment: @DanBron you learn something new everyday. I suspect your suggestion is the more contextually accurate. Deleting mine! :)

Comment: I'd prefer to have it open. Learning from other's questions (and answers following) is one sure way to run into as yet unknown areas of English.